# I am trying to use JPA in my springboot project, but after adding the dependencies when I try to run the spring boot application, it shows error

Tags: spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.JPA.Tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootJPAExamples</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bootJPAExamples</name>
    <description>JPA USING SPRING BOOT</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: If you don't show us your pom.xml at minimum we really can't help you.

Comment: I have added pom.xml ,can you check it

Comment: Add the _text_ to your question. Not a picture of code.

Comment: If my answer doesn't help you, please also post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the required dependencies should look something like this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When you add the jpa dependency to your project it will try to wire a `dataSource` bean. You will need to provide adequate properties for this bean to be configured or your project startup will fail.

Your properties file should look something like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDBname
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

*Mind that this db should exist in your MySQL instance.*